# Customizing the dropdown style in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

If you click this link, [Bootstrap navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar), and then scroll down to "Responsive Navbar" and click the dropdown, it has an upside down triangle on the dropdown and it doesn't sit flush against the navbar. I currently have this style.

I would like this style of dropdown: [Other Bootstrap navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

I tried googling, maybe I am just dense, but shouldn't I be able to pick and choose the style with some css or by using a certain class?

Comment: The first link goes to Bootstrap 2 documentation, and the second link to Bootstrap 3. So are you asking how to update your Bootstrap library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both themes are very similar, but the style you have currently seems to be out of date(2.3.2). If you use bootstrap 3.3.6 you will have the theme you wish to have.

The class dropdown-menu has a property of Top. You give this the desired value so it stays flush with the navbar. This class works in both bootstrap 2 and 3.

```
.dropdown-menu {
  top: 95%;
}
```

Demo Fiddle of the class

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bwwLg396/2/

Comment: O wow someone being helpful instead of taking a dump on my question :D

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can apply custom CSS to the Bootstrap navbar if you want to.  You will need to use a separate custom stylesheet.